# Control how NAs are displayed with pandas styler

Tags: python, pandas, nan, pandas-styles

I am trying to use the `na_rep` argument of `df.style.format()` to control how cells with NaN are shown in the table.

Documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.format.html

Reproducible code:

```
import numpy as np; import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"col1":[1,2,3],"col2":[1,np.nan,2]})
df.style.format(na_rep='.')
```

I get this error message.

> TypeError: format() got an unexpected keyword argument 'na_rep'

Do you know a work around?  Tks!

Comment: I had a different error, and needed to pip install Jinja2. After that code ran but doesn't format (using python 3.7 and latest version of pandas in case it works for your env.). Looking into it.

Comment: what version of pandas are you using? that was valid since 1.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a grey color for the text and the background of NA cells to hide the NAs

```
import numpy as np; import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"col1":[1,2,3],"col2":[1,np.nan,2]})
s = df.style
s.applymap(lambda x: 'color: #E5E5E5' if pd.isnull(x) else '')
s.applymap(lambda x: 'background: #E5E5E5' if pd.isnull(x) else '')
```

This is what it looks like:

[image]